# R beyond strict correlation, finding "Islands"

Tags: r, correlation

I have a dataset with 12 variables that represent different levels of chemical properties(sugar, acidity etc..) and a variable that is a quality grading.

The goal is to find out, what leads to a good quality wine.

First i tried strict correlation and find only very weak, meaningless ones.

Now i have this idea, that there might be what i called "islands" in the data, where for example the acidity and the sugar level is just the right level for a great wine. I am new to R and analysis and maybe i am completely wrong in my idea, but does anyone know how i could possibly search for those kind of "islands"

Thank you very much

Comment: You're looking for clustering.

Comment: Ok, now i know the term, thank you, that is a start, does anyone have any additional tip how to make it happen ?

Comment: you can look at trees as well, like rpart for example, but this would not give you "islands" but rather would partition the data

Comment: An easy analysis would be cutting the variables into factors with say 5-10 levels (depending on the number of obeservations you have). You can then do a linear regression for "quality ~ f.sugar + f. acidity + ...". This assumes no interaction though.

Comment: Can someone comment on the validity of my general idea ? again i am a real beginner, i understand correlation and that was just an idea. Hope i am not wasting your time  or mine.

Comment: Correlations or regressions with continuous variables are will propably not give anything usefull. As your asumption of a "sweetspot" is propably right.

Comment: If quality is your response, you may be dealing with something related to [*response surface methodology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_surface_methodology)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lessons explain most of the analyses discused here... on wine data... in R!
https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat857/node/223